# Android Canvas drawBitmap takes too long on Android Oreo, while it works fine on Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, draw

I want to make normal flappy bird game and this is how obstacle class looks like.  Here in method ConfigureNextFrame() I'm updating obstacle positions and drawing with normal canvas.drawBitmap() method. It takes about 20ms on Android Oreo to draw obstacles, while Android Lollipop is running smoothly. This time is too long because there are other things to draw also, and i can only achieve about 15fps. I'm using normal game loop with SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder. I have also tried Drawable.draw(canvas) method but results are same.

```
private final int obstacleframemove = Variables.esar * Variables.obstacleframemove;

private Bitmap obstacledrawableup;
private Bitmap obstacledrawabledown;
private float left;
private float utop;
private float dtop;
private float right;
private float ubottom;
private float dbottom;

public Flappy50Obstacle(int position, int part) {

    obstacledrawableup = Methods.GenerateScaledBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Variables.currentcontext, R.drawable.flappy50_up), 2f * Variables.easyscalea);
    obstacledrawabledown = Methods.GenerateScaledBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Variables.currentcontext, R.drawable.flappy50_down), 2f * Variables.easyscalea);

    left = (int) Variables.width;
    utop = position - obstacledrawableup.getHeight() - part;
    right = left + obstacledrawableup.getWidth();
    ubottom = utop + obstacledrawableup.getHeight();

    dtop = position + part;
    dbottom = dtop + obstacledrawabledown.getHeight();

}

public void ConfigureNextFrame(Canvas canvas) {

    if (Flappy50Panel.GetMoveBackgroundItems()) {

        left -= obstacleframemove;
        right -= obstacleframemove;

    }

    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();

    canvas.drawBitmap(obstacledrawableup, left, utop, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(obstacledrawabledown, left, dtop, null);

    Log.d("TIMEINMILLIS", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - x));

}

public Rect GetCoordinatesUp() {

    Rect r = new Rect();

    r.left = (int) left;
    r.top = (int) utop;
    r.right = (int) right;
    r.bottom = (int) ubottom;

    return r;

}

public Rect GetCoordinatesDown() {

    Rect r = new Rect();

    r.left = (int) left;
    r.top = (int) dtop;
    r.right = (int) right;
    r.bottom = (int) dbottom;

    return r;

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, you need to be specific.  You've done a pretty good job explaining your issue but you left it up to us to figure out what your question is.

Comment: Thanks for you reply ! I'm interested in how canvas changed from Android API 21 to API 27, because only the difference in APIs is the only thing that makes frame rates different. Could you tell me how to optimize drawing on canvas ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Problem solved by changing **PNG** bit depth from 8 to 32